# Unable to locate package xinetd

Tags: package-management, xinetd

I tried to install `xinetd` by the command `sudo apt-get install xinetd`. I got this error message

```
Unable to locate package xinetd
```

Why?
Isn't it supposed to be under `init.d` folder?

Comment: What repositories you have enabled? (in `/etc/apt/sources.list`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**xinetd** is in the **main** repository the top tick in this screenshot

[image: Software Sources]

Make sure this is enabled first. I would then update your server by clicking on the Download from drop down box and choose other...

[image: Other server]

Then click then click the select best server button which test by pin the fastest server for you obviously any servers down at the time will not be tested you can then close the window and the system will automatically update apt you can then use either software centre, synaptic or terminal to download your package.

Hope this helps

Comment: My pleasure, btw if you have any problems with apt failing to connect to server just search for best server again as it can only choose from "up" servers.